# REXX - Parse from CSV File

Tags: parsing, csv, rexx

I'm having trouble parsing a CSV from a text file and was wondering if you guys could assist me.  So far I have the following,

The CSV file (DATA.txt) looks something like this, it will always have 15 fields all separated by a comma.  Not all fields are mandatory so some will be filled and some are blank.

```
Seattle,Lastname,Firstname,DOB,SEX,etc,etc
Seattle,Lastname,Firstname,DOB,,etc,etc
Portland,Lastname,Firstname,DOB,SEX,,,etc
Portland,Lastname,Firstname,DOB,SEX,etc,etc
```

And here is my REXX Code

```
SOURCEFILE = "C:\DATA\DATA.TXT"
IF A=2 THEN DO COUNTER=1 TO LINES(SOURCEFILE)
    PARSE VALUE LINEIN(SOURCEFILE) WITH CITY "," LAST_NAME "," FIRST_NAME "," MOM_NAME "," MIDDLE_NAME "," DAD_NAME "," DOB "," etc "," etc "," etc "," etc "," SEX "," etc "," etc
    CALL SETCURSOR 4,23
    CALL CREATEDATA
END

CREATEDATA:
CALL TYPE CITY
CALL PRESS TAB
CALL TYPE LAST_NAME
CALL PRESS TAB
CALL TYPE DATE(U)
CALL PRESS TAB
CALL TYPE FIRST_NAME
CALL PRESS TAB
CALL PRESS ENTER
RETURN
```

I'm not sure if I should be using ARG or VAR when parsing or if I wrote first two lines correctly.  I know for fact that my CREATEDATA function works properly because I'm getting the "CITY" typed in but not the parsed value.  Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

1) `Lines(SourceFile)` on a Windows system probably involves reading the entire file to count CR-LF sequences.  Then your `Parse value LineIn(SourceFile)` loop reads it again.  The typical Rexx way to do this would be:

```
Address SYSTEM 'TYPE' SourceFile with output stem Lines.
Do Counter = 1 to Lines.0
    Parse var Lines.Counter ...
End
Drop Lines.
```

At least, as long as the file isn't so large that keeping it in an array is costly in memory.

2) You're flowing down into `CreateData` at the end of your loop, which is why you're seeing "CITY".  You need a `Return` or `Exit` after that `End` instruction.

3) In light of #2, it's obvious that the `Parse` is never being executed, because `City` is uninitialized (the value of an uninitialized variable in Rexx is its name in upper case).  It's conditional on `A=2`, which must not be the case.

Comment: According to Cowlishaw's Rexx book, the LINES built in function may return the number of lines in the referenced file or, if that cannot be determined, a '1' where a non-zero count would be appropriate, otherwise a '0'. I use ooRexx on windows quite a bit and can confirm that ooRexx does not count all lines, it just returns a 0/1. I use the following to read files one line at a time: DO WHILE LINES(filename) > 0; PARSE VALUE LINEIN(filename) with... ; END

Comment: The result of `Lines()` is implementation-dependent.  Some implementations return a count, others just 1 or 0 as you've observed.  It's also why I prefer to load the stem up: `Lines.0` is an actual count.

Answer (score 1):

One question what is the purpose of if A=2 then in

```
IF A=2 THEN DO COUNTER=1 TO LINES(SOURCEFILE)
```

if A != 2 the loop is bypassed. I suspect your program should be:

```
SOURCEFILE = "C:\DATA\DATA.TXT"
DO COUNTER=1 TO LINES(SOURCEFILE) 
    PARSE VALUE LINEIN(SOURCEFILE) WITH CITY "," LAST_NAME "," FIRST_NAME "," MOM_NAME "," MIDDLE_NAME "," DAD_NAME "," DOB "," etc "," etc "," etc "," etc "," SEX "," etc "," etc
    CALL SETCURSOR 4,23
    CALL CREATEDATA
END

RETURN   /* prevent the fall through to createdata */

CREATEDATA:




---------------------------
```

The parse statement has the following basic format

parse [source] [parse-control]

where [source] icludes

arg   -  arguments on a procedure call
   pull  -  data pulled off the stack
   var   -  data comes from a variable
   value ... with  data supplied inline

So your parse could be done like

```
   linein = LINEIN(SOURCEFILE)
   PARSE var linein CITY "," LAST_NAME "," FIRST_NAME "," MOM_NAME "," MIDDLE_NAME "," DAD_NAME "," DOB "," etc "," etc "," etc "," etc "," SEX "," etc "," etc
```

or

```
    DO COUNTER=1 TO LINES(SOURCEFILE) 
        CALL SETCURSOR 4,23
        CALL CREATEDATA LINEIN(SOURCEFILE)
    END

    RETURN   /* prevent the fall through to createdata */

    CREATEDATA:
    parse arg CITY "," LAST_NAME "," FIRST_NAME "," MOM_NAME "," MIDDLE_NAME "," DAD_NAME "," DOB "," etc "," etc "," etc "," etc "," SEX "," etc "," etc
```

Finally ass ross said you should try and aviod lines(sourcefile) as it involves reading the entire file